How to run map() after fetch has completed React
I'm trying to fetch data and then get my React App to map through the data to render each product on the page.
However it fails to find the data to perform the .map() and I assume that's because the fetch hasn't completed when it starts looking for the data.
How can I tell the map to occur after the data has been fetched? Here is an example of my code trying to get this working:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


const App = () => {

  const [productData, getproductData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  const fetchData = async() => {
    fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=0')
      .then((res) =>
      res.json())
      .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      getproductData(response);
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <div className='products'>
      {productData.products.map(product => (
        <div className='product' key={product.id}>
          <div className='productInfo'>
            <div className='productTitle'>
              <div className='productBrand'>{product.brand}</div> 
              <div className='productName'>{product.title}            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App


You switch the definition of productData, at first you define it as an array but then it's used as an object. It would be best to define the initial value to match the structure from the API or to just be null and then handle that case.

the issue arises because productData.products is undefined initially before the data is fetched. To handle this, you can add a check to ensure productData.products exists before map over it.
{productData.products && productData.products.map(...)}
or you can also use
{ productData?.products.map(...)}

Thank you and well done on your first response it worked great, I didn't realise you could straight up combine a check and the map like this. It made me realise that a whole component and it's scritpts relied on this data being there, so I wrapped all of the scripts and the components return in an if (props.productData.products) {} and it worked doing wonders. Thank you again I think this was very graceful

Before fetching data, productData.products is undefined.
Replace productData.products.map to productData.products?.map will be helpful.
And in this code snippet:
`const fetchData = async() => {
    fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=0')
      .then((res) =>
      res.json())
      .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      getproductData(response);
    })
  }`

I think getproductData(response.data) will be correct.
Thanks.

Thank you this works and this operation wasn't one I'd used or heard of in all honesty, more info here for others: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining
